# How to handle # in cucumber Gherkin language as a value and not to comment out

Tags: cucumber, gherkin

```
Scenario Outline: verify handling "#" in code 
Given user logs in to url "<url>"
When User enters Username "<UserName>" in username field
And User enters Password "<password>" in Password field
Then user should be logged in as <"screenName">

 Examples:
 |username|password|screenName|
 |user    |pwd#    |User 1|
```

In above scenario, I want to pass the password "pwd#" as a parameter.

How do I handle this by ensuring the # is not treated to comment out the remaining portion of the line.

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a backslash and it seemed OK. The editor didn't like it but it ran.

```
Given I have a \#2 web services
```

step looked like:

```
Given(/^I have a \\\#(\d+) web services$/) do |num|
  expect(num).to eq(num.to_i.to_s)
end
```

Output looked like:

```
 @pound
  Scenario: client rest GET
    Given I have a \#2 web services

1 scenario (1 passed)
1 step (1 passed)
0m0.005s
```

BTW, I only added the \# in the step to begin with then ran cuke. I told me what the step def characters needed to be. It's a good friend if you know what I mean.

Comment: Thanks Dave, for your answer.

Comment: I just realized that, when you enter the parameter for password as "pwd#", the remaining portion of the line shows as if its commented out. But when you run the feature, it runs even the commented portion (i.e screenName = User 1). So, I am good now.